# Figuring out when a comment was deleted in order to understand edit and question

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

Is there any way as a user to see when comments were deleted or would I have to have moderator privileges for that?

I've been looking at [pull one line at a time from text file to use as a variable in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899321/pull-one-line-at-a-time-from-text-file-to-use-as-a-variable-in-powershell), its comments and [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43899321/revisions).

The edit adds a message about an exception, but the code in the post doesn't contain a call to the command that threw the exception. My current guess would that the OP posted a comment and later on deleted it.

Is there a way for me to figure out that a comment was deleted, or should I just ignore such questions?

Comment: Being able to see deleted comments is moderator only. There are no deleted comments on that question though.

Comment: What "message about an exception" was added by the edit? I only see formatting and capitalization changes in that edit. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks both of you for your input. Indeed the exception, which has been quoted in the second edit, was there before. I just kind of skipped it, it seems.